# Find and Delete a Node in XML, using libxml2 and xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2

I have a big XML file which has multiple nodes like below;

`<my_section enum="ORANGE" name="blah">`
`</my_section>`
`<my_section enum="APPLE" name="blah blah"`>
`</my_section>`

etc..

I need to look for a specific 'enum' type like APPLE and delete that my_section node for APPLE.

I tried using Xpath, but i am not sure what should be the eval string here. If I just give my_section, then all the sections will come. I need to match on the enum though. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a>
    <my_section enum="ORANGE" name="blah"> </my_section> 
    <my_section enum="APPLE" name="blah blah"> </my_section>
    <my_section enum="ORANGE1" name="blah1"> </my_section> 
</a>
```

Using XPATH, you may be able filter out the nodes needed. I have added a root element just to test. Change as needed.

```
/a/my_section except /a/my_section[@enum = "APPLE"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!!. One additional question, can we have wildcard match here?, like if we have ORANGE and ORANGE1 and i need to pick both, can i have some thing like my_section[@enum = "ORANGE*"]. I tried this , but didn't work. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use contains function then : `//a/my_section[contains(@enum,"ORANGE")]`

Comment: Excellent!!..thanks E.Wiest and Slkrasnodar for your timely help :)

Comment: @E.Weist, for my learning, is there a reason why you suggest to use contains()  over equality check? I think, I have seen you using it in some other place but really not sure of it.